# Lifting Line Theory - The general lift distribution

Tags: fixed-wing

While studying the derivation of the lifting line theory using different text books like `Fundamentals of Aerodynamics by John D. Anderson`, Precisely when deriving the general lift distribution over the wing, it assumed the following equation
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\theta) = 2bV_{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_{n} \sin(n\theta)
\end{equation}

How did he just assumed that multiplying the Fourier series expansion by $2bV$ is a good assumption, I mean there must be a mathematical motive to do so, and I could not find anyone explaining the equation, so I hope someone can help me with that.

Thanks in advance

P.S

I suspected that the value  $2bV$ represents the the lift distribution at the origin as in the equation

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\theta) = \Gamma_{0} \sin \theta
\end{equation}

But still I can't relate both quantities. I thought that I can derive it from the equation

\begin{equation}
\alpha_{i} = - \frac{w}{V_{\infty}} = \frac{\Gamma_{0}}{2bV_{\infty}}
\end{equation}

but to do so I think we should assume that the induced angle of attack is equal to one and I don't understand that physically.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: 2bV is Gamma zero (eq 5.47 in my version)

Comment: When I compared both equations I deduced that the quantity is actually gamma zero but I still don't how he got from equation 5.47 to the Fourier expansion series equation.

Comment: Your question concerns the lift over span (3D) while my answer was for the 2D case.